# Update div after POST method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page with a form for registering a new user. After pressing the submit button the following action method (which checks if a user is already in DB and inserts a new one if there isn't) executes in my controller.

```
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    int result = this.isUserInDB(model.Email);
    ViewBag.numberOfEmails = result;

    if (result == 0)
    {
        this.insertNewUserInDB(model.Name, model.Surname, model.Password, model.Email);
    }
    return View();  
}
```

Now I would like to have a div, on the same page as the form, where I would display a notification message if:

- a user is already in the db
- a user was inserted in the db

I can't accomplish this now, because I always return the same view. I tried changin the return type of the action method to void, but that displays a blank page.

How can I solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't accomplish this now, because I always return the same view.

That's not a problem. In your view you could have some conditional logic:

```
if (Model.NewUserInserted) 
{
    <div>A new user was created</div>
}
else if (Model.UserAlreadyExists)
{
    <div>The specified user already exists</div>
}
```

of course you should now write your view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int NumberOfEmails { get; set; }
    public bool NewUserInserted { get; set; }
    public bool UserAlreadyExists { get; set; }
}
```

the controller action that is initially rendering this view should pass an empty model:

```
return View(new MyViewModel());
```

and your POST action should set the corresponding properties:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    int result = this.isUserInDB(model.Email);
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel();
    viewModel.NumberOfEmails = result;

    if (result == 0)
    {
        this.insertNewUserInDB(model.Name, model.Surname, model.Password, model.Email);
        viewModel.NewUserInserted = true;
    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.UserAlreadyExists = true;
    }
    return View(viewModel);  
}
```

and of course your view should be strongly typed to the view model:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and you should get rid of all `ViewBag`.